# Integrated development environment for OCaml

Tags: ocaml

What is the most popular and versatile IDE for OCaml. 
I read the Visual studio code with vscode-ocaml (which include Merlin) is a good option.Can i add vsCode-Ocaml plugin to visual studio ? 
Is there a better alternative than this ?

Comment: Recommendation question are explicitly off-topic on SO because they tend to attract opinionated answers and discussion about which is better, which is not a good fit for the format here. Please see [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: https://discuss.ocaml.org/ would be a better place to ask these kinds of questions I think.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of personal taste, some will prefer vim with merlin, other emacs. There is also [atom](https://atom.io/packages/language-ocaml) that comes with some ocaml plugins. This is for editing the source code (code completion thx to merlin).

With respect to VS with ocaml, this [site](https://medium.com/@bobbypriambodo/starting-an-ocaml-app-project-using-dune-d4f74e291de8) is a nice description (which may be what triggers your question).

As REPL, you can use emacs with tuaregs, utop, atom can also wrap ocaml REPL, [Jupyter](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/jupyter/) with ocaml connection.